# Program type already present: com.google.gdata.util.common.base.Preconditions

Tags: android, uservoice

I am trying to integrate https://github.com/uservoice/uservoice-android-sdk/ and get the error: 
Program type already present: com.google.gdata.util.common.base.Preconditions

I am trying to exclude that dependency, but not sure which module it's being pulled from.
Excluding gdata-java-client or gdata doesn't resolve the error. Any pointers to the dependency to be excluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
compile ('com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.+') {
    exclude module: 'signpost-core'
}
```

The 'signpost-core' dependency has a transitive dependency on 'com.google.gdata'. Since signpost-core already exists in your project, you have to exclude it.